# How to write an S3 object to a file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-io, amazon-s3

What's the fastest way to write an S3 object (of which I have the key) to a file? I'm using Java.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While `IOUtils.copy()` and `IOUtils.copyLarge()` are great, I would prefer the old school way of looping through the inputstream until the inputstream returns -1. Why? I used IOUtils.copy() before but there was a specific use case where if I started downloading a large file from S3 and then for some reason if that thread was interrupted, the download would not stop and it would go on and on until the whole file was downloaded.

Of course, this has nothing to do with S3, just the IOUtils library.

So, I prefer this:

```
InputStream in = s3Object.getObjectContent();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
while( (count = in.read(buf)) != -1)
{
   if( Thread.interrupted() )
   {
       throw new InterruptedException();
   }
   out.write(buf, 0, count);
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Note: This also means you don't need additional libraries

Comment: What should I do if the file is gzipped?

Comment: Throws Index OOB exception.

Comment: Or simply do `Files.copy(in, Paths.get("/my/path/file.jpg"))` as @Jonik answered

Answer (score 40):

Since **Java 7** (published back in July 2011), there’s a better way: [`Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) utility from [`java.util.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html).

> Copies all bytes from an input stream to a file.

So you need *neither* [an external library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680998/56285) nor rolling your own [byte array loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7681791/56285). Two examples below, both of which use the input stream from `S3Object.getObjectContent()`.

```
InputStream in = s3Client.getObject("bucketName", "key").getObjectContent();
```

**1)** Write to a new file at specified path:

```
Files.copy(in, Paths.get("/my/path/file.jpg"));
```

**2)** Write to a temp file in system's default tmp location:

```
File tmp = File.createTempFile("s3test", "");
Files.copy(in, tmp.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

(Without specifying the option to replace existing file, you'll get a `FileAlreadyExistsException`.)

Also note that [`getObjectContent()` Javadocs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#getObjectContent()) urge you to **close the input stream**:

> If you retrieve an S3Object, you should close this input stream as
>   soon as possible, because the object contents aren't buffered in
>   memory and stream directly from Amazon S3. Further, failure to close
>   this stream can cause the request pool to become blocked.

So it should be safest to wrap everything in try-catch-finally, and         do `in.close();` in the finally block.

The above assumes that you use the official SDK from Amazon ([`aws-java-sdk-s3`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22aws-java-sdk-s3%22)).

Comment: This is a much better approache than the old way of looping through bytes.

Comment: I would rather do `Files.copy(in, Paths.get("/my/path/file.jpg"))`. Better to get the path without going through the File

Comment: If you don't need to catch consider [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: @davidvandebunte you can use try with resources even if you need to catch... See this bit in the docs you referenced: "A try-with-resources statement can have catch and finally blocks just like an ordinary try statement"

Answer (score 9):

The AmazonS3Client class has the following method:

```
S3Object getObject(String bucketName, String key)
```

The returned S3Object has the method...

```
java.io.InputStream getObjectContent()
```

..which gets the object content as a stream. I'd use IOUtils from Apache Commons like this:

`IOUtils.copy(s3Object.getObjectContent(), new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath)));`

Comment: what should I do if the file is gzipped?

Answer (score 4):

What about this one liner using a TransferManager:

```
TransferManagerBuilder.defaultTransferManager
  .download("bucket-name", "key", new File("."))
```

Answer (score 3):

From **AWS SDK for Java v2 released in 2017**, you can just specify a `Path` for writing to the file.

```
s3.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(),
        ResponseTransformer.toFile(Paths.get("multiPartKey")));
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#download-object

If you need a `File`, you can use `toFile` method.

```
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
s3.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(),
        path);
File file = path.toFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(myS3Object.getObjectContent());

            // path where to save the file
            File myFile = new File("/home/ayoub/Android/release.apk");

            //save content to file
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(apkFile, content);

            // OPTIONAL if you'd like to return a resource
            Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource( content );
```