# How do I read the content of a file in Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, file-io, amazon-s3

I have a file in `Amazon S3` in bucket `ABCD`. I have 3 objects `("folderA/folderB/folderC/abcd.csv")` which are folders and in the final folder I have a `.csv` file `(abcd.csv)`. I have used a logic to convert it to `JSON` and load it back into another file which is a `.txt` file in the same folder `("folderA/folderB/folderC/abcd.txt")`. I had to download the file locally in order to do that. How would I read the file directly and write it back to the text file. The code which I have used to write to a file in S3 is below and I need to read a file from S3.

```
 InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16));
 ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
 metadata.setContentLength(json.length());
 PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketPut, filePut, inputStream, metadata);
 s3.putObject(request);
```

Comment: You seem a bit confused about S3 objects: you can have an object with a key like `"folderA/folderB/folderC/abcd.csv"` but that's just *one* object. S3 objects are always files, not folders. (Even though for example in S3 web UI `folderA` etc do show up as folders if you've created objects with such keys.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to write an S3 object to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679924/how-to-write-an-s3-object-to-a-file)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you should get the object `InputStream` to do your need.

```
S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
```

Pass the `InputStream`, `File Name` and the `path` to the below method to download your stream.

```
public void saveFile(String fileName, String path, InputStream objectData) throws Exception {
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File newDirectory = new File(path);
        if (!newDirectory.exists()) {
            newDirectory.mkdirs();
        }

        File uploadedFile = new File(path, uploadFileName);
        out = new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile);
        byte[] fileAsBytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(fileAsBytes);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
        dos.write(fileAsBytes);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (dos != null) {
                dos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After you Download your object read the file and make it to `JSON` and write it to `.txt` file after that you can upload the `txt` file to the desired bucket in `S3`

Comment: I actually used this to read but could not change this to JSON directly and load this to .txt file in s3. Thanks for the answer. This helps

Comment: The IO code in `saveFile()` is way more complicated than necessary. As shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34445210/56285), basically `Files.copy(objectData, new File("/my/path/file.jpg").toPath());` suffices.

Comment: Using `available()` is not recommended, in fact it is quite discouraged. See the javadoc for an explanation: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()). Basically you can't count on an implementation returning the total number of bytes in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other java libs for downloading or reading files without downloading.
Check the code please, I hope it is helpful for you. This example for PDF.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripperByArea;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Result;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;
import java.io.File; 
   //..
   // in your main class 
   private static AWSCredentials credentials = null;
   private static AmazonS3 amazonS3Client = null;

   public static void intializeAmazonObjects() {
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
        amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
    }
   public void mainMethod() throws IOException, AmazonS3Exception{
        // connect to aws
        intializeAmazonObjects();

    ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName);
    ListObjectsV2Result listObjectsResult;
do {

        listObjectsResult = amazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(req);
        int count = 0;
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : listObjectsResult.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.printf(" - %s (size: %d)\n", objectSummary.getKey(), objectSummary.getSize());

            // Date lastModifiedDate = objectSummary.getLastModified();

            // String bucket = objectSummary.getBucketName();
            String key = objectSummary.getKey();
            String newKey = "";
            String newBucket = "";
            String resultText = "";

            // only try to read pdf files
            if (!key.contains(".pdf")) {
                continue;
            }

            // Read the source file as text
            String pdfFileInText = readAwsFile(objectSummary.getBucketName(), objectSummary.getKey());
            if (pdfFileInText.isEmpty())
                continue;
        }//end of current bulk

        // If there are more than maxKeys(in this case 999 default) keys in the bucket,
        // get a continuation token
        // and list the next objects.
        String token = listObjectsResult.getNextContinuationToken();
        System.out.println("Next Continuation Token: " + token);
        req.setContinuationToken(token);
    } while (listObjectsResult.isTruncated());
}

public String readAwsFile(String bucketName, String keyName) {
    S3Object object;
    String pdfFileInText = "";
    try {

        // AmazonS3 s3client = getAmazonS3ClientObject();
        object = amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
        InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(objectData);
        document.getClass();

        if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

            PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

            PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

            pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pdfFileInText;
}
```